# Laptops with adjustable screens (Popular designs are not proper to human anatomy)

Tags: laptop, monitors, displays

When I look at my laptop's screen I feel that my backbone is not straight. And, sometimes I feel neck pain. If I move down my chair (or put the laptop higher) then I have sore arms and shoulders. None of the following images make sense to me. Nobody puts the screen that much high, nor they move their eyes down to look at something on the screen. At the position that is claimed to be correct, you need to move your eyes till the end to see the windows bar.

I would feel much comfortable if I had a chance to move the screen up just the half of the height of the screen in the picture below. So to say, there should be some distance between the keyboard and the screen.

[image]

Besides being light-weight, laptops should have sliding hinges that allow users to move the screen up or down. I know that it would change the center of the gravity, but this problem can be solved with a simple trick by the designers. Maybe, there are some companies that are doing it already. I would really like to know the name of these companies.

Besides, with the developing technology (or it feels like that) a small projectors can be used instead of screens on laptops.

[image]

EDIT: Price range would be between 500 and 1000 USD

Comment: If you are looking for something like tablet & laptop think about Thinkpad Twist or HP: http://www8.hp.com/us/en/ads/elitebook-revolve/landing.html or Dell Latitude XT3:http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Dell-Latitude-XT3-Convertible.92919.0.html.

Comment: I'd recommend to be more specific about your requirements because adjustable screens are quite common nowadays. Tell us more and put some price range.

Comment: @belford
Yes you are right about adjustable screens being very common these days. However none of them (what I've seen so far) move up and down vertically. You cannot set the distance between the screen and the keyboard of the laptop on those popular types of laptops. I hope I made it clear for you. Thanks

Comment: Forget about expensive sliding thing, even with something similar to radio antenna concept designers can accomplish this task. As you know those antennas hold very small place when they are folded. The rest is finding a good way to handle the cabling.

Comment: is Acer Aspire R7 close to what you need? http://static.acer.com/up/Resource/Acer/Notebooks/AGW2%20Aspire%20R/photo%20Gallery/20130315/R7_571-photo-gallery-02.png

Comment: @belford That can be one option. I am still open to other recommendations though, I would like have broad discussion on this question. I wonder what other people think, and also want to know what others prefer. Thank You Belford

Comment: I expect something like the [Asus Transformer](https://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks-Accessory/ASUS_Transformer_Pad_Mobile_Dock_AD03_TF103_series_TF303_series/) which has a disconnect-able display/keyboard combined with a 3rd party "case" or stand for holding the display up would help. I remember an article about someone who taped up heavy duty velcro mount points in the various places they commonly set up shop.

Comment: @matt wilkie
That seems to be a smart solution if there are appropriate cables to be used between this product and your pad. But, when you take your pad and keyboard to, for example, the library you should still need to carry  some kind of stand with you to place the screen on the head level.

Comment: @Karel no cables needed if keyboard is Bluetooth. But yes still would need to pack around stand.

Answer (score 1):

After some google search, I have found a company which do something similar to what I need. I am not sure if I can find this product in my country. And I also doubt whether their are still in business because they website and products look like out-of-date. I am going to contact with them. Question is still current.

[http://www.amazon.com/FlyBook-Advanced-Laptop-Computer-A210914-77F21-511112/dp/B001JI6BP0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001JI6BP0)

[image]

http://en.flybook.pl/view/modele

EDIT: If the links go dead keyword for the search is 'Flybook'.

Comment: Could you provide a list of specs and perhaps a picture? If the link were to go dead, for example, this answer would be useless. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like the company doesn't exist anymore. I can't find anything about the company in the commercial register, and on the address provided on the website, there is another company.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @szoszk Well, I am sure that they are not the only one who design this kind of laptops that I am interested in. But, It is difficult to find with google search. Are you also interested in these type of designs? It seems that at the end I will buy a used laptop and modify it myself :)

Comment: Not really, because I use a regular computer, and have my monitors on a few thick books. But would it be an option for you, to use an external mouse and keyboard? This way you could put your laptop higher.

Comment: @szoszk That is okay to use an external keyboard and mouse when you use the laptop regularly as desktop in an office or home.